# Android Studio 3.1 - cannot connect to USB device

Tags: android-studio-3.1

I just updated Android Studio to 3.1. When I try to build and run an app that formerly worked fine, I don't see the ADB window with either the virtual device or my tablet.

Tablet is a Ellipsis, developer mode is enabled, USB debugging is enabled. There is no entry under 'tools' for ADB.

Comment: Can you access the usb storage? Also try accessing it manually with [adb](https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/) to see if it works.

Comment: I can see the tablet in an explorer window - it shows up as a music device, can't drag and drop files into it. ADB devices shows it.

Comment: Android Studio opens the file on a fresh start, shows a red note at the lower left when I try to run = "Error running 'program': No target device found.

Comment: Enabled USB file transfer - can read and write the tablet now. It was set to USB charge only.USB debugging still enabled on tablet.

Comment: OK. Dumb error, caused by me not knowing where to look. Two configurations were set up - the one I was using had the debugger turned off. Duh. It's working now.